# MAkefile LINK.cc - main.o being put after the linked libraries and causes an error

Tags: c, makefile, linker

I'm following this [tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/software-engineering/how-to-write-a-makefile) on how to make a makefile. I've made one below for my project. However, there is a problem with the linking stage and the order of the files.

The tutorial says that `LINK.cc` makes use of cxx,
cxxflags, ldflags and is defined as

> $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)

The command line gives this output which indicates that `main.o` is being placed after linking when it should be before hand.

```
gcc  -I./include -I/usr/local/include/upm  -c -o utils.o utils.c
g++  -I./include -I/usr/local/include/upm -L/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/local/lib/ -lrabbitmq -lupmc-rn2483 -lupmc-utilities -lupmc-rn2903  main.o utils.o  -o myprogram
```

Correct command:

```
gcc main.o -I./include -I/usr/local/include/upm -L/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/local/lib/ -lrabbitmq -lupmc-rn2483 -lupmc-utilities -lupmc-rn2903  utils.o  -o myprogram
```

My question is how do I fix the makefile?

Makefile

```
program_NAME := myprogram
program_C_SRCS := $(wildcard *.c)

program_CXX_SRCS := $(wildcard *.cpp)

program_C_OBJS := ${program_C_SRCS:.c=.o}

program_CXX_OBJS := ${program_CXX_SRCS:.cpp=.o}

program_OBJS := $(program_C_OBJS) $(program_CXX_OBJS)

program_INCLUDE_DIRS := ./include /usr/local/include/upm

program_LIBRARY_DIRS := /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/local/lib/

program_LIBRARIES := rabbitmq upmc-rn2483 upmc-utilities upmc-rn2903 

CPPFLAGS += $(foreach includedir,$(program_INCLUDE_DIRS),-I$(includedir))
LDFLAGS += $(foreach librarydir,$(program_LIBRARY_DIRS),-L$(librarydir))
LDFLAGS += $(foreach library,$(program_LIBRARIES),-l$(library))

CC = gcc
CXX = g++

LINK.o = $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)

LINK.cc = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)

.PHONY: all clean distclean

all: $(program_NAME)

$(program_NAME): $(program_OBJS)
    $(LINK.cc) $(program_OBJS) -o $(program_NAME)


clean:
    @- $(RM) $(program_NAME)
    @- $(RM) $(program_OBJS)

distclean: clean
```

This is the dir structure:

```
.
├── include
│   └── utils.h
├── main.c
├── Makefile
└── utils.c
```

Comment: The variable `program_C_OBJS` contains "utils.o", and `program_CXX_OBJS` contains "main.o", is that right?

Comment: @Beta thanks for your reply. No I don't thinks so main.c and utils.c are both c files so there should be no C++ object files. I included the directory tree in my original question. thanks

Comment: Then what is the pattern? You want 'main.o` before the flags, and all other objects after the flags?

Comment: Its producing this pattern, main.o is after the flags. How do i change the make file to fix this? `g++  -I./include -I/usr/local/include/upm -L/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/local/lib/ -lrabbitmq -lupmc-rn2483 -lupmc-utilities -lupmc-rn2903  main.o utils.o  -o myprogram
`

Answer (score 1):

Don't put libraries (-l) in `LDFLAGS`, put them in `LDLIBS` instead. The linking rule used by `make` is:

```
$(LINK.cc) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

The change for your makefile is

```
LDLIBS += $(foreach library,$(program_LIBRARIES),-l$(library))
[...]
$(LINK.cc) $(program_OBJS) -o $(program_NAME) $(LDLIBS)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you want in the general case, but this should give you what you're asking for.

Add this:

```
LINKFLAGS :=$(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)
```

and change the `$(program_NAME)` rule to this:

```
$(program_NAME): $(program_OBJS)
    $(CC) main.o $(LINKFLAGS) $(filter-out main.o, $(program_OBJS)) -o $(program_NAME)
```

Other refinements are possible once you have this working.